# ng-repeat recursive loop crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, recursion

Okay so i have the following directive:

```
    app.directive("menuItem", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl: 'tpl/directives/menu-item.html',
        scope: {
            category: '='
        },
        link: function(scope,element, attr){

        }
    };
});
```

This is being called as such:

**Top level**

```
    <!-- list -->
<ul class="nav" ng-controller="NavController">
    <menu-item ng-repeat="category in categories" category="category"></menu-item>
</ul>
<!-- / list -->
```

**menu-item.html**

```
    <li>
    <a href="" class="auto" ng-if="category.subcategories.length > 0">
          <span class="pull-right text-muted">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right text"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down text-active"></i>
          </span>
        <span>{{category.name}}</span>
    </a>
    <a ui-sref="app.ui.googlemap" href="#/app/ui/googlemap" ng-if="category.subcategories.length <= 0">
        <span>{{category.name}}</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav dker" ng-if="category.subcategories.length > 0">
        <menu-item ng-repeat="cat in category.subcategories" category="cat"></menu-item>
    </ul>
</li>
```

There are no console errors it basicly crashes before i can get the console up.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @ngLover can you give an example ?

Comment: plz provide fiddle ?

Comment: @ngLover im not quite good at making fiddles sadly erm but i will try hang on

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1g0s2e0x/1/  it doesnt quite work as in my application but wasnt quite sure how to make it hope you can see what i am doing